# Is the SO prototypejs tag correct?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, tags

I just posted a question to StackOverflow regarding the PrototypeJS library. I tagged my question with `[prototypejs]` because I figured the `[prototype]` tag was too generic, probably for function prototypes. But `[prototypejs]` only has ~89 usages making me question if it's a duplicate tag, and if I should have tagged my question as `[prototype]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tag Overload Exception

`[prototype]` can mean various things depending on the context, and most likely there are some questions about PrototypeJS that are tagged simply prototype, but the one you used is *better*.

[Seems like there were](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototypejs+prototype) other people with the same doubt, and said *What the hell, better safe than sorry*.

Answer (score 1):

[prototype] *is* too generic - it's the name of a language feature in JavaScript, and should probably have been limited to that...

Unfortunately, it isn't. Of [the 912 questions tagged `prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype), a good many of them have nothing to do with prototypes and everything to do with the Prototype.js library. Which makes it rather difficult to find questions about, say, [prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototypal-inheritance)...

I commend you for choosing a better tag... Let's hope your thoughfulness isn't rewarded with indifference.