# Cleaning the Prototype tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki, ambiguous-tags

#### Summary

The [prototype](/questions/tagged/prototype) is ambiguous. After reviewing the current questions, the tag wiki should be updated.

*Progress update* I have retagged over 1700 questions. We **need** a **better** tag wiki excerpt. If no-one proposes a generic tag wiki (excerpt), I'm going to edit the wiki to the JavaScript prototype, since I'm not skilled enough in other meanings of `prototype`.

Even the smallest suggestions (comments?) are appreciated.

---

**Re-tagging help and tools**
The [prototype](/questions/tagged/prototype) tag covers 2.3k questions, and is used to mark [prototypejs](/questions/tagged/prototypejs) and [prototype-programming](/questions/tagged/prototype-programming) questions. The ambiguity of this tag has been discussed before <sup>[1]</sup>.

I decided to review the [prototype](/questions/tagged/prototype) tag. Since this tag contains many questions, I'd appreciate any help.

To increase the efficiency/speed of retagging, I have created [this Userscript](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/121541). 
An explanation for the tool can be found at the linked [userscripts.org page](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/121541). These two screenshots ([question.png](http://s3.amazonaws.com/uso_ss/15390/large.png?1324993117) and [tag-overview.png](http://s3.amazonaws.com/uso_ss/15391/large.png?1324993240)) show the effects of the tool.

---

**Tag wikis**
When the ambiguity has disappeared, the [prototype](/questions/tagged/prototype) tag (wiki) has to be improved, to avoid future confusion.

- **Prototypes** are mainly used for JavaScript-prototype questions. Should the tag be generalised, to also cover other [prototype-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) languages?
- Should [prototype](/questions/tagged/prototype) become a *synonym* of another tag, or vice versa?

Expected answers: Suggestions for an improved tag excerpt + wiki.

---

### <sup>[1]</sup> Related meta questions

- [Is the SO prototypejs tag correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49027/is-the-so-prototypejs-tag-correct)
- [Question about prototypal inheritance need to be disambiguated from questions about the Prototype JavaScript library](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81767/question-about-prototypal-inheritance-need-to-be-disambiguated-from-questions-ab)

Comment: Current progress: 548 edited questions. At the end of the trip, the prototypejs tag will cover more on-topic questions, resulting in a correct tag usage. I've done enough for today.

Comment: Thank you for helping keep SO clean! :)

Comment: 643 remaining questions tagged prototype, as of now. @Community If you're skilled in the relevant topics, please correct the tags (filter tags at the right side of the page).

Comment: This has been annoying me too recently so I've spend quite a lot of time today retagging the latest questions (of which there were quite a few). As of right now, I don't *think* there are any [tag:prototypejs] questions wrongly tagged with [tag:prototype].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have replaced the outdated tag wiki with the following, because [prototypejs](/questions/tagged/prototypejs) tagged [prototype](/questions/tagged/prototype) questions started to pop up again. The current tag wiki is showing how to find the right questions / audience efficiently, without explaining the Prototype concept.

Can anyone improve this?

---

### [Tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3694778/revisions)

> In prototype-based languages, the prototype of an object is a set of properties which is inherited by all objects which are based on this object.

### [Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3694777/revisions)

> See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming
>
> Search tips:
>
> - Questions concerning the [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) library are tagged [prototypejs](/questions/tagged/prototypejs).
> - Questions about the concept of Prototypical programming are marked by [prototype-programming](/questions/tagged/prototype-programming). Not to be confused with: [oop](/questions/tagged/oop).
> - Add `-[js]` to your search query, if you are looking for questions which are *not* about the JavaScript language. Example: [`[prototype]
>     -[javascript] example`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprototype%5D+-%5Bjavascript%5D+example)
> - Questions regarding function prototypes ([c](/questions/tagged/c)) should be tagged [function-prototypes](/questions/tagged/function-prototypes).