# Are there some tools available to edit Tags?

Tags: discussion

From time to time I do some editing of tags. Most often in the PHP domain, like for example cleaning up the ([most often](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135800/147909)) superfluous [php5](/questions/tagged/php5).

What I would like to know if there are some tools and if it is accepted to use them to do some legwork, for example:

> For questions that have the tags [php](/questions/tagged/php), [session](/questions/tagged/session) and [php-session](/questions/tagged/php-session) remove the tag [php-session](/questions/tagged/php-session)

What do you think if such a tools does not exist, and one would write some script that can be used for such jobs via the API?

Answer (score 2):

Once, I wanted to clean up *lots* of questions (meta: [Cleaning the Prototype tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117226/169101)).
For this purpose, I made the following script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/121541, where you can find out what the tool does:

> ### Tag overview
>
> By default, a confirmation dialog appears when attempting to submit a tag edit.
>   By default, the question summaries at the tag overview page (containing questions) of an ambiguous tag will not expand.
>
> A button is added at the upperleft corner of a question overview page. This button can be used to open multiple questions at once, without having to click at the separate links.
>
> ### Question page
>
> At a question page, some buttons will show up. It's possible to retag the questions by clicking once at the button.
>
> Anything which was prefixed by "By default" can be customised by editing variables at the source code.
>   At all times, the page adjustments can be toggled by pressing SHIFT + ESC

**Emphasis: Do not just retag the questions, also fix other problems in the post when possible!**

Comment: About your remark: Yes, I most often do that if I spot such issues. The "Thanks in Advance" / "With Respect" / "Regards, Name" for example . But sometimes it's just about burning down the tags when not needed as there is nothing else to clean up.